# Find $n$ points that minimize the supremum distance between any point and the closest point in the set

Tags: geometry, optimization, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, hausdorff-distance

Let $(\mathcal{X}, d)$ be a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Find

$$\operatorname*{argmin}_{\mathcal{Y} \in [\mathcal{X}]^n} \sup_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \inf_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} d(x, y)$$

That is, find a set of $n$ points that minimizes the maximum distance between any point and the closest point in the set.

I am especially interested in the case where $d$ is the [Euclidean metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) and $\mathcal{X}$ is any of the following:

- unit L$_p$ [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)): $\|x\|_p \leq 1$
- unit L$_p$ [sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere): $\|x\|_p = 1$
- unit [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex): $x \geq 0, x \cdot 1 = 1$

for any of $p \in \{1, 2, \infty\}$. Does this problem have a name in the literature? Are there any efficient algorithms for obtaining exact or approximate solutions in these special cases?